# How to convert true color to ncurses color values

Tags: c++, ncurses

So, I want to make an algorithm that converts hex color to ncurses color values.

For example:

```cpp
std::string bar = "#A400C6";
init_pair(1, foo(bar), COLOR_BLACK); // foo will return COLOR_MAGENTA (or 5)
attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
wprintw(win, "Example");
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

I have no idea how to write it.

(I tried to make when foo finds similar  values in array of arrays of int, but it doesn't work)

Edit: here's my broken algorithm

```cpp
class RGB 
{
public:
  uint8_t r;
  uint8_t g;
  uint8_t b;

  RGB(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
  {
    this->r = r;
    this->g = g;
    this->b = b;
  }
};

uint8_t cvaluesForRAndB[3] = {0, 24, 178};
uint8_t cvaluesForG[4] = {0, 24, 104, 178};

// Here the default colors in my kde terminal
RGB terminalColors[8] = {{0, 0, 0}, {178, 24, 24}, {24, 178, 24}, {178, 104, 24}, {24, 24, 178}, {178, 24, 178}, {24, 178, 178}, {178, 178, 178}};

bool compareRGB(RGB a, RGB b)
{
  return a.r == b.r && a.g == b.g && a.b == b.b;
}

int foo(std::string hex)
{
  std::string vals[3] = splitWithLength(2, (hex[0] == '#') ? hex.substr(1, 6) : hex); // (if need) splitWithLength will return array with std::string. for example splitWithLength(2, "000cba") will return {"00", "0c", "ba"}

  uint8_t uintVals[3];
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    uintVals[i] = std::stoi(vals[i], nullptr, 16);
  }

  RGB res(findClosest(cvaluesForRAndB, 3, uintVals[0]), findClosest(cvaluesForG, 4, uintVals[1]), findClosest(cvaluesForRAndB, 3, uintVals[2]));

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (compareRGB(terminalColors[i], res))
    {
        return i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

(It's all in header file)
(Yes, very bad code.)

Comment: You only want to use the basic colours or are you intending to use `init_color` to change the basic colours?

Comment: There's a lot of questions raised (see [example](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#compare_picsmap)).

Comment: @user4581301, only basic. Without `init_color`.

Comment: Groovy. You have the right idea, so it might be a good idea to show what you did for `foo`. Yeah, it doesn't work, but it's probably somewhere close, and even if it isn't someone can show you where it went off the right path.

Comment: If you're willing to make not-noticable sacrifices to accuracy, then http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1645360c1c9b75b7 (or similar) should be *super* fast.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xYoabT9aM shows my shortcut to be 17 asm instructions, no branches